# Asp.Net Core structuremap IoC Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, structuremap

I have been at this for hours. I have an existing code base, working just fine.
Moved over to Asp.Net Core and the latest Structuremap and now I am having issue with my `DbContext`.

I get this error

> The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts

Seems as if SM is NOT creating a single `DbContext` per request. But I cannot figure out WHY?

Here is a snippet from the repository.

```
    private readonly EntityContext _context;
    protected readonly DbSet<T> _dbSet;

    public Repository(EntityContext context)
    {
        _context = context;

        _dbSet = _context.Set<T>();
    }
```

Here is my multiple ways I have tried to register the context with SM.

```
    public StructureMapRegistry()
    {                                        
        var unique = new UniquePerRequestLifecycle();
        For<DbContext>().LifecycleIs(unique).ContainerScoped().Use<EntityContext>().ContainerScoped();
        For<EntityContext>().LifecycleIs(unique).ContainerScoped().Use<EntityContext>().ContainerScoped();

        //ForConcreteType<EntityContext>().Configure.Transient();

        //For<DbContext>().ContainerScoped().Use<EntityContext>();

       // For<EntityContext>().Use(() => new EntityContext());

        For<IUnitOfWork>().ContainerScoped().Use<UnitOfWork>();
        For(typeof(IRepository<>)).Use(typeof(Repository<>));
    }
```

Comment: Did you follow the setup instructions [from here](https://github.com/structuremap/StructureMap.Microsoft.DependencyInjection#example-1)? Note that it says *You can populate the container instance in one of two ways*. If you copy the code as is, you are registering it *both* ways.

Comment: Also, I don't know if it is a mistake or not, but it says on that page *For this integration package to work properly, you need version 1.1 of ASP.NET Core*. As it is worded, it sounds like it is not compatible with ASP.NET Core 2.0, although it is possible they meant **at least** 1.1.